# GCC custom section length definition, out of range control

Tags: gcc, linker, avr-gcc

I'm using GCC for and specific MCU target (to be accurate for AVR) I have a special external memory that I try to define a custom Section by using following command in linker options

```
-Wl,--section-start=.customsection=0x821000
```

and then using **attribute** inside the code just like this:

```
unsigned char X __attribute__((section (".customsection")));
```

everything is correct and works fine. But how can I define some limitation to this custom section that force the GCC linker to raise an error in case of overrun? By limitation I mean a way to define length of the section or end-address.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can only specify the length in a linker file.

You would have to copy the linker file for your MCU and modify it.

For more information and examples see:
- https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/create-new-section-ram
- https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/custom-linker-script-atmega